# How can I add a password to this JDBC:ODBC connection string that is trying to connect to an MS Access database

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, odbc

This is the connection string that is currently working on a non-password protected MS Access database.

this code snippet is from our properity file:

```
db.url = jdbc:odbc:Driver\={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq\=C:\Inventory.mdb;DriverID\=22;READONLY\=true
```

How do I add a password to this connection string for a MS Access DB protected by a database password (**Non-ULS**)?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it a database password, or a Jet user-level security password? @Tommy's answer below will work for ULS, but not for a db password.

Comment: It's a db password.  The below solution does not work.  

Do you have a solution that will work? :)

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a DNS and then use the DSN in your connection string?

Comment: Yes, currently that is the work around we are using. We have an OS level DNS that has the password to the DB. We set the DSN to the url for our org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.  We would prefer to use the above connection string. Do you know of a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: From any of the research that I have found, I cannot see that ODBC supports a database (file) level password. Only OLEDB seems to support this. Also, it does not seem that there is a JDBC-OLEDB bridge. Sorry WillPhil, perhaps someone else knows a secret ODBC parameter to send a file level password :(

**Edit** - Perhaps not 'only' OLEDB, but nothing on the default MS Access ODBC driver.

Comment: Are you sure the database password is needed? It really is one of the most useless faux-security features I've ever seen, no matter how much they've strengthened the encryption in A2007.

Comment: @David: Could you pass along a link that would describe why it's a faux-security feature? It'd be useful to explain to the boss why it's a bad idea.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't have a link. To me, it's just common sense. If you use it, you have to embed the password in the table links, or in your relinking code, and that means it's discoverable by a hacker. Sure, you can distribute an MDE front end and encrypt the front end, but it's still just a nuisance to the hacker. If you need real security, then you should store your data in something other than a Jet/ACE data store. Also, the database password doesn't provide any mechanism for user access control, i.e., varying presentation/access according to the user.

Answer (score 3):

Referenced from here:  [Java Support](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/bridge.doc.html)

```
db.url = jdbc:odbc:Driver\={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}Dbq\=C:\Inventory.mdb;DriverID\=22;READONLY\=true; UID\=me;PWD\=secret
```

Comment: This is what happens when you have to play with access... :-(

Comment: I edited my question to make it more specific.  The solution above only works for ULS passwords. Any thoughts on what do to in the case of a plain db password?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To work on password protected MS Access Database 2003/2007 use the below code snippet

```
package jdbcExample;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class JDBCExampleOfMSAccess2007 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Start of Program");
        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String url=null,userID=null,password=null;
        String dbFileName=null;
        String sql=null;

        dbFileName = "C:\\temp\\MYTestDatabase.accdb";
        userID = "Admin";
        password = "Ganesh@123";
        <b>url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"+
                "DBQ="+dbFileName+";"+
                "Uid="+userID+";"+
                "Pwd="+password+";"; </b>
        sql = "SELECT * FROM tblUserProfile";
        System.out.println("url = "+url); 

        try
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userID,password);
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            if(rs!=null)
            {
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    System.out.print("User ID = "+rs.getString("User ID"));
                    System.out.print(" User Name = "+rs.getString("User Name"));
                    System.out.print(" Password = "+rs.getString("Password"));
                    System.out.println(" Access Type = "+rs.getString("Access Type"));
                }
                rs.close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
        try {
                stmt.close();
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("End of Program");
    }
}
```

My connection string url was

```
    url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"+
            "DBQ="+dbFileName+";"+
            "DriverID=22;READONLY=true;"+
            "Uid="+userID+";"+
            "Pwd="+password+";";
```

and I was facing one problem while connecting to MS Access Database the stack trace as below.

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]General error Unable to open registry key Temporary (volatile) Ace DSN for process 0x162c Thread 0x1e98 DBC 0x38f5924                                                              Jet'.
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at jdbc.JDBCForMSAccess2007.main(JDBCExampleOfMSAccess2007 .java:37)
```

To overcome this problem simply I removed the **"DriverID=22;READONLY=true;"** in url string and the problem get solved :)
The given code snippet I have tested on password protected MS Access 2003 and 2007 Database and work well.

Hope that it will helpful to do new experiment.

Comment: There can be 2 types of passwords for an Access db file: a separate password for each user with Jet user-level security (MDB format only); a single database password which is required for any connection to the db.  Your answer relates to the first type of password, but the question is about the second type.

Answer (score 0):

I know you're asking for ODBC, but is it impossible to use OLEDB, as in [the connect string provided on ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access):

```
  Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;
```

I don't know that the Jet ODBC driver provides any support for database passwords, which were not introduced until Jet 4 (and are completely worthless in any version of Access/Jet/ACE).