# Creating ODBC Data source java

Tags: java, ms-access, ms-access-2007, jet

I found this video which shows how to connect to access database :

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ujJ4H9RpC7c

My question is : Is it possible to create ODBC datasource programatically ?

or from command line or anything like that?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to create a windows ODBC DSN programmatically with pure Java.  It is possible with C++ and other native approaches.

However, you can connect to an Access MDB file directly (via ODBC) using a JDBC URL of the form:

- `String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={MicroSoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=c:/path/to/myaccessfile.mdb"`

This way you do not need to have predefined DSN.  You might also want to review the answers to this question:

- [How can I add a password to this JDBC:ODBC connection string that is trying to connect to an MS Access database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578886/how-can-i-add-a-password-to-this-jdbcodbc-connection-string-that-is-trying-to-co)

Answer (score 0):

From the command line, you can use an utility named [odbcconf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388579%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I guess that if you need to do that programatically, you'll need to use WinAPI somehow.