# How to connect UCanAccess to an Access database encrypted with a database password?

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, ms-access-2010, ucanaccess

I've developed a Java application (a dictionary) with an Access database to store the words of the dictionary and I'm getting ready to distribute it.
I want to encrypt my database with a password to prevent people to access my words.
When I set a passwords the Java code shows this Exception

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: Decoding not supported.  Please choose a CodecProvider which supports reading the current database encoding.
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver.connect(UcanaccessDriver.java:247)
```

Here is my connection code before encryption of my database with password ....

```
String s1="jdbc:ucanaccess://";
String user="";
String pass="";
String s4="words.accdb";

public void connectToDB(){
        //database connection
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(s1+s4,user,pass);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //end of database connection
    }
```

Here is the code after the encryption with password for example 12345...

```
String s1="jdbc:ucanaccess://";
String user="";
String pass="12345";
String s4="words.accdb";

public void connectToDB(){
        //database connection
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(s1+s4,user,pass);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //end of database connection
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Steps of How to connect UCanAccess to an Access database encrypted with a database password

Step 1:
Add these two packages to your project (jackcess-encrypt.jar, bcprov-ext-jdk15on-152)

You can download the two packages from the following links:

[Jackcess Encrypt](http://jackcessencrypt.sourceforge.net/)
[Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html)

Step 2:
You have to add this class to your project folder

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import net.ucanaccess.jdbc.JackcessOpenerInterface;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.CryptCodecProvider;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Database;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DatabaseBuilder;

public class CryptCodecOpener implements JackcessOpenerInterface {
         @Override
    public Database open(File fl,String pwd) throws IOException {
       DatabaseBuilder dbd =new DatabaseBuilder(fl);
       dbd.setAutoSync(false);
       dbd.setCodecProvider(new CryptCodecProvider(pwd));
       dbd.setReadOnly(false);
       return dbd.open();
    }
  //Notice that the parameter setting autosync =true is recommended with UCanAccess for performance reasons. 
  //UCanAccess flushes the updates to disk at transaction end. 
  //For more details about autosync parameter (and related tradeoff), see the Jackcess documentation. 
}
```

like this

[image]

step 3:
use the following connection code

```
public void connectToDB(){
            try {
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://words.accdb;jackcessOpener=CryptCodecOpener", "user", "pass");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

You can also watch this video...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TT6MgBBkRSE

Answer (score 0):

UCanaccess supports encryption through the dependencies injection pattern.

-You have to add jackcess-encrypt and all related dependencies to your project

-You have to code a class implementing the `net.ucanaccess.jdbc.JackcessOpenerInterface` as suggested in the ucanaccess web site

-You have to pass the name of the above class in the jdbc url:
if  you named the implementation class `com.pippo.Bingo`
then you have to build the jdbc url in this way:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://c:/db/your_db_name.mdb;jackcessOpener=com.pippo.Bingo", "sa", pwd);
```

Comment: Thanks dear i know that you answer is correct but what should i write in the class that implements JackcessOpenerInterface interface or when i should call the open method which located inside JackcessOpenerInterface interface

please Explain More .......
coz too much people have have the same question

Comment: and I would like to help you.
You just need to copy the  class that implements JackcessOpenerInterface showed in the ucanaccess web site, change its name, pass the chosen (complete )name in the jdbc url e.g. jdbc:ucanaccess://c:/db/your_db_name.mdb;jackcessOpener=com.plete.Name;
UCanAccess will call the open method.

Comment: see also my answer in the ucanaccess forum(when sourceforge will be newly available)

Comment: now it shows this exception

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/crypto/InvalidCipherTextException
 at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.CryptCodecProvider.createHandler(CryptCodecProvider.java:114)`
from the return inside the open methode
`return dbd.open();`

Comment: thanks i have founded the solution which is that we must add another jar file 
`http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html`
thanks a lot.................

Comment: While you're at it, why not create a new database driver ... *sigh*

Comment: @Constantin Because five lines of code (to solve an encryption issue) are less than several tens of thousands. You should know the requirements before proposing different solutions even if they are much better from your point of view.

Comment: @jamadei I was being sarcastic about creating a driver. Also, please do not patronize me, I knew his damn requirement but suggested a java solution for embedded database distributions. Had the OP come here asking how to drink water from a sponge, you would be here describing it to him in detail, but doesn't mean its a useful answer in my opinion

Comment: @Constantin I know, but your sarcasm was misplaced, the step to be done is easy. And ucanaccess is 100% java. I go to drink wine like a sponge. I don't patronize you, have a nice day/night.

Answer (score -2):

Your Link to the jdbc driver (s1) seems to be invalid.

Look at the pattern i found while googleing it from [this Site](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/260924-how-to-connect-access-2007-database-with-a-password/)

```
 String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\IJTS EXAMPLES\\Database11.accdb;PWD=1234";
```

Here is a sample from [a Site](http://www.coderanch.com/t/301387/JDBC/databases/JDBC-MS-Access)

```
private void initializeConnection()
{

Connection con ;
try
{

// Load Class Definition for Database Driver
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

// set this to a MS Access DB you have on your machine
String curDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
String filename = curDir +"/test.mdb";

String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=c:\\test.mdb;READONLY=true";

// Get connection from the DriverManager
con = DriverManager.getConnection( database,"Admin","test" );


} catch (Exception e) {

System.out.println("Database Connection Problem");

}

}
```

Please not that you have to change the string by replacing parts with your credentials

Comment: no my link is valid, it works fine without password
how can i write that database connection statement with ucanaccess??
because jdbc:odbc bridge is removed from jre8

Comment: If it is removed, why are you still using MSAccess? Can you tell us the reason you cannot use a pure java solution?

Answer (score -2):

I assume you have set the database password from within MSAccess, encrypting it.

To connect to this type of database, you need the correct connection string and connect via odbc.

Here is a link to get the connection strings for MSAccess
https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

A good post on the subject can be found here   [How can I add a password to this JDBC:ODBC connection string that is trying to connect to an MS Access database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578886/how-can-i-add-a-password-to-this-jdbcodbc-connection-string-that-is-trying-to-c)

I would suggest you use a different type of embedded database to do all of this for java. Use h2, which is far better pure java solution

http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html

code example

```
public class HelloWorld {

    /**
     * Called when ran from command line.
     *
     * @param args ignored
     */
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        // delete the database named 'test' in the user home directory
        DeleteDbFiles.execute("~", "test", true);

        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test");
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();    
        stat.execute("create table test(id int primary key, name varchar(255))");
        stat.execute("insert into test values(1, 'Hello')");
        ResultSet rs;
        rs = stat.executeQuery("select * from test");
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
        }
        stat.close();
        conn.close();
    }    
}
```

**Where are the Database Files Stored?**

When using database URLs like jdbc:h2:~/test, the database is stored in the user directory. For Windows, this is usually C:\Documents and Settings\ or C:\Users\.

If the base directory is not set (as in jdbc:h2:test), the database files are stored in the directory where the application is started (the current working directory).

When using the H2 Console application from the start menu, this is /bin. The base directory can be set in the database URL. A fixed or relative path can be used.

When using the URL jdbc:h2:file:data/sample, the database is stored in the directory data (relative to the current working directory). The directory is created automatically if it does not yet exist.

It is also possible to use the fully qualified directory name (and for Windows, drive name). Example: jdbc:h2:file:C:/data/test

**Passing the User Name and/or Password in the URL**

Instead of passing the user name as a separate parameter as in
`Connection conn = DriverManager. getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test", "sa", "123");`

The user name (and/or password) can be supplied in the URL itself: `Connection conn = DriverManager. getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test;USER=sa;PASSWORD=123");`

Comment: Why do you need MSAccess anyway? Use H2

Comment: i dont know use it : )

Comment: I can help you use it ... give me a moment to code it for you